# application's trust level in the configuration

Tags: asp.net, .net, trust

How can I fix this exception I'm receiving in ASP.NET?

Description:

> The application attempted to perform an operation not allowed by the
>   security policy.  To grant this application the required permission
>   please contact your system administrator or change the application's
>   trust level in the configuration file.

Exception Details:

> `System.Security.SecurityException: Request for the permission of type
>   'System.Security.Permissions.ReflectionPermission, mscorlib,
>   Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089'
>   failed.`

Comment: Is this a .NET web.config file?

Comment: Improved formatting and made it clearer what is being asked (based on assumption).

Comment: More info needed. WWWWWH?

Answer (score 0):

This issue may occurs due to the improper handling of the token / session id. After successfully authentication how  your are creating the token / session id. Is it windows authentication / form based